# Why does this integral (of the Schwarz kernel) define a holomorphic function in the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

(This may look very silly to you but I don't understand the reason that was given to me, nor do I have the knowledge to find out by myself).

The domain for $z$ is the *open unit disc* $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C} | \vert z \vert < 1\}$.

Here $\sigma$ is a real-valued function of bounded variation on $[0,2\pi]$. $$f(z):=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}d\sigma (\theta).$$

In any compact $K\subset D$, the modulus of the integrand is bounded by $(1+\lambda)/(1-\lambda)$, so $|f(z)|$ is bounded by $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}|d\sigma (\theta)| = \frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}V_{[0,2\pi]}(\sigma) $ ($V_{[0,2\pi]}(\sigma)$ is the total variation of $\sigma$).

Why does this show that $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $D$? I was told "by Weirstrass' theorem" but that theorem deals with sequences of holomorphic functions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to recall the Weierstrass Uniform Convergence Theorem:  If $ f_n $ are holomorphic functions on an open set $ U \subset \mathbb C $ such that $ f_n $ converges to $ f $ uniformly on compact subsets of $ U $, then $ f $ is holomorphic.

Now we simply need to realize the integral as the limit of a sequence of holomorphic functions.  For this we simply go back to the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjies integral (we don't need Lebesgue-Stieltjes since $ \sigma $ is of bounded variation).  In particular recall that when it exists it is simply the limit of sums of the form

$$
f_n(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} k(z,\tilde\theta_i)(\sigma(\theta_{i+1})-\sigma(\theta_i))
$$

where in your case $ k(z,\theta) $ is the Schwarz kernel (or in general any function that is analytic in $ z $ and continuous in $ \theta $).  By the details you've provided, these sums converge uniformly to the integral on compact subsets of $ U $.  Furthermore they are analytic on $ D $ since they are finite sums of analytic functions.  Hence by Weierstrass's theorem, $ f(z) $ is analytic on $ D $.

In general it is often fruitful to prove things about continuous objects by passing to statements about sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $f$ is a continuous function of $z$. Now, the bound you have for the integrand and the fact that the integrand is holomorphic on $D$ allows you to use Morera and Fubini to conclude.

Comment: I think this solution is equally important to have seen.